# How to unlock all doors with the key on a 2006 Mazda

Tags: mazda, locks, key

If I turn the driver-side door key clockwise, release it, and turn it clockwise again, all the doors on the vehicle lock.  However, if I turn it counter-clockwise, release it, and turn it counter-clockwise again, only the drivers side door unlocks.  Is this lack of symmetry normal, or is there something wrong with my car?  If the behavior is normal for my car, is there any way to change it so I can unlock all doors with the key alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my 2004 Mazda3, turning the key and *holding it* unlocks all doors.